# Get an image of a text with optimized font size and centering in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, text, scale, center

I have a string chain of characters that I would like to display as big as possible within a rectangle frame, in a centered way. I know :

- how many characters maximum can have my input
- the dimensions of the rectangle

It has to :

- find the best font size and displays the result.

Here is the MATLAB code

```
color = 'k';
txt = '1';
howManyCharMaximum = 7;
boxWidth = 250;
boxHeight = 100;

%% comput: Now I assume one char is as wide as tall
howManyChar = strlength(txt);
marginHoriz = mod(boxWidth,howManyCharMaximum); %in points
subRectangle.width = (boxWidth-marginHoriz)/howManyCharMaximum;
subRectangle.height = boxHeight;
[fontSize,idx] = min([subRectangle.width, subRectangle.height]); %the largest square that fits in a rectangle

%%
hFigure = figure('MenuBar', 'none', ...
                 'ToolBar', 'none', ...
                 'Units', 'points', ...
                 'Position', [0 0 boxWidth boxHeight], ... % x y from bottom left of screen to botleft of the fig
                 'Color', 'w'); 
hAxes = axes; hAxes.Visible = 'off';

%pos:=botleft vertex of the string
switch(idx)
    case 1
        x = floor((boxWidth-howManyChar*fontSize)/2);
        y = floor((boxHeight-fontSize)/2);
    case 2
        addMarginHoriz = (subRectangle.width-subRectangle.height)*howManyCharMaximum;
        x = floor((boxWidth-howManyChar*fontSize)/2);
        y = 0;
end
hText = text(x, y, ...
            txt, ...
            'Units', 'points', ...
            'FontSize', fontSize, ...
            'HorizontalAlignment', 'left', ...
            'VerticalAlignment', 'middle', ...
            'Color', color);
```

But for some reasons I can't figure out, this is what it returns unfortunately -- a decentered character:

[image]

Would anyone know where I did a mistake pleaase ? By thanking you in advance.

Comment: “Now I assume one char is as wide as tall”. I presume that is your mistake. Letters tend to be taller than wide.

Answer (score 1):

I used normalized units for text as its lot easier to find the center and then it worked with the proper alignment. Note that a slight offset will still exist because actual figure grid has more space on left then right and at bottom then top. You can experimentally adjust it if you wish

```
color = 'k';
txt = '18998';
%howManyCharMaximum = 7; I didnt use this one
boxWidth = 250;
boxHeight = 100;

%% comput: Now I assume one char is as wide as tall
howManyChar = strlength(txt);
%marginHoriz = mod(boxWidth,howManyCharMaximum); %in points
subRectangle.width = (boxWidth)/howManyChar;
subRectangle.height = boxHeight;
[fontSize,idx] = min([subRectangle.width, subRectangle.height]); %the largest square that fits in a rectangle
%%
hFigure = figure('MenuBar', 'none', ...
                 'ToolBar', 'none', ...
                 'Units', 'points', ...
                 'Position', [0 0 boxWidth boxHeight], ... % x y from bottom left of screen to botleft of the fig
                 'Color', 'w'); 
hAxes = axes; hAxes.Visible = 'off';
%plot(0,0)
%pos:=botleft vertex of the string

x = floor(boxWidth/2);
y = floor(boxHeight/2)

hText = text(0.5, 0.5, ...
            txt, ...
            'Units', 'normalized', ...
            'FontSize', fontSize, ...
            'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
            'VerticalAlignment', 'middle', ...
            'Color', color);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! You can set the axes position to fill the figure, then you’ll get rid of the asymmetry I think.